# Knife tool cuts through unexpectedly

Tags: edit-mode

I've had a problem where the knife tool keeps cutting through to the other side of the geometry, even though X-Ray is turned off, along with "cut through" and all other settings I can see. Does anyone know why it cuts through to the other side?[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't see anything wrong in your settings... and even if X-Ray was turned on it shouldn't cut through if this option is off (at least it doesn't in my Blender). But I also can't see anything cut through in your screenshots.